# Can dynamic url parameters be handled in app.yaml for google appengine for php?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Is it possible to use `app.yaml` in google app engine for php to convert database driven pages with url parameters (?= after php page in the url) to a more human readable form? If not app.yaml is there another way?

For example: **www.testpage.com/shoes?id=red-shoes**

converted to something like: **www.testpage.com/shoes/red-shoes**

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it cannot be done with app.yaml. The reason is, if you took something like what you're describing, eg:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*?)/(.*)
  script: /\1?id=\2
```

App Engine would correctly identify that pattern /shoes/red-shoes and route it to /shoes?id=red-shoes. Except it treats /shoes?id=red-shoes as the *filename* (which obviously doesn't exist) instead of a script + query string.

So, the way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be something like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*?)/(.*)
  script: /mydbhandler.php
```

The pattern /(.*?)/(.*) matches patterns like /shoes/red-shoes and sends all such requests to /mydbhandler.php. Inside /mydbhandler.php you should inspect
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
which will be "/shoes/red-shoes" and handle it from there inside your PHP code.